# Tabulator refresh table every x seconds

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have the following code. It fetches the JSON data from an external URL and loads it into Tabulator.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>
    <div id="example-table"></div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
const url = "http://85.17.219.9/test.json";

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxConfig:{
        method: 'GET'
    },
    ajaxURL: url,
    index:"MessageID",
    autoResize:true,
    layout:"fitColumns", //layout options
    placeholder:"Awaiting Data...",
    columns:[
        {title:"timestamp", field:"timestamp", headerSort:false},
        {title:"latitude", field:"latitude", headerSort:false},
        {title:"longtitude", field:"longtitude", headerSort:false},

    ],

    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response){
        //url - the URL of the request
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
        //response - the JSON object returned in the body of the response.

        return response; //pass the data array into Tabulator
    },

});
table.setSort("latitude", "asc")
</script>
        </body>
</html>
```

It works fine. The JSON data changes every x seconds. I want to reload the table every x seconds. How can I achieve this without reloading the whole page?

I am new to JS/Tabulator...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you should be able to do that with a combination of `setInterval`  and `table.replaceData()`.

```
setInterval(() => table.replaceData(), yourInterval);
```